# How to add a property to the instance of Script?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

According to the Gradle [documentation 13.3](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:project_api):

> When Gradle executes a script, it compiles the script into a class
>   which implements Script.

We can add extra properties to the `Project` object by putting their declarations into the `ext`-block. For instance:

```
ext {
    springVersion = "3.1.0.RELEASE" //added to the Project object
    emailNotification = "build@master.org" //added to the Project object
}
```

Is it possible to add a property to the `Script` object by `ext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add properties local to the script, you need to use the `def` directive.

```
def mySrciptProp = "hello world"
```

Note that all classes that implement [ExtensionAware](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ExtensionAware.html) can use the extra properties extension ([ExtraPropertiesExtension](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html)).

The [Script](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Script.html) object does not implement this and therefore extra properties cannot be added to it.

Comment: Not clear, def is being used to define local variables, not extra properties.

Comment: From the documentation _Local variables are declared with the def keyword. They are only visible in the scope where they have been declared. Local variables are a feature of the underlying Groovy language._

Comment: Edited my answer to include an explanation for it.